# Unity 2D parallax background for all screen sizes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I come from the flash world and new to Unity and struggling with backgrounds in 2D for mobile. That is, struggling with understanding how to create a parallax background that will fit on all mobile devices. Actually doesn't even have to be parallax. I've read several post on the issue and tried several things but none of them work for me.

I've tried scripts that change the camera size, that scale the images etc. Outcome is never good as one scales the images and they don't look right and the other methods don't display critical parts of the background.

What have I missed with 2D backgrounds and how can I address it?

Thank-you

Answer (score -2):

As you are new to Unity explaining each and everything may take brief answer.

Have a look on this script it will help you if it doesn't comment and ask.

**Code :**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Done_BGScroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float scrollSpeed;
    public float tileSizeZ;

    private Vector3 startPosition;

    void Start ()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        float newPosition = Mathf.Repeat(Time.time * scrollSpeed, tileSizeZ);
        transform.position = startPosition + Vector3.forward * newPosition;
    }
}
```